# Referencing a database

Tags: citing

I'm looking for a template of how to reference a database, such as data.stackexchange.com. Should it simply be considered as an electronic source, or is there a certain way such items should be referenced?

Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! This isn't really related to TeX (or friends) *per se* since it's a question on what a particular citation format is, rather than (say) exactly how to typeset the citation.  Usually, things like `bibtex` and `biber` mirror real-life citation formats---they don't specify their own.  I'm not really sure there is a specific way to cite a database---it seems to just follow the `article` format: http://www.easybib.com/reference/guide/mla/database

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use an Biber you can set it with **@online**. It is the command for internet reference